# WordPress Nested Second Add Action is not working

Tags: wordpress

Second add_action function is not working but I am not getting any error. if I take the second add_action out of the function it works outside but since I want it to work on specific pages I can't work with that.

Do you have any suggestion how may I fix this problem?

```
add_action('current_screen', function ($current_screen) {

    if ('smart_board' == $current_screen->post_type && 'post' == $current_screen->base) {

        add_action('add_attachment', function ($post_ID) {
            $file = get_attached_file($post_ID);
            $path = pathinfo($file);
            $file_slugified_name =  $path['filename'];
            $file_prefix =  'smart_board_';
            $file_dir = $path['dirname'];
            $file_extension = $path['extension'];

            $newfilename =   $file_prefix . $file_slugified_name;
            $newfile = $file_dir . "/" . $newfilename . "." . $file_extension;

            rename($file, $newfile);
            update_attached_file($post_ID, $newfile);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: did your $current_screen if condition is working?

Comment: yes it is working

Comment: There must be something else going wrong because the nested `add_action`s and inline function are fine. I've tested these nested `add_action`s in the same way you have them here - obviously I don't have the same function and screens as you are using, but I was able to set the description & caption on the uploaded image using the same structure as you have without issue.